# How to read data from file, pass it to another function and return the return value of the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, fs

I'm trying to return arr when final() is called....

```
  function final(){
        var arr;
        fs.readFile("/my/path/", 'utf8' ,(err, data) => {
            arr = parsing(data);
            arr.splice(-1,1);


      });
        return arr;
    }
```

It keeps returning undefined. Even though arr inside the readFile brackets gives me an array...

The possible duplicate discusses printing whereas I need a value to use somewhere else. 
How can I use the value arr in another function/module?

Answer (score 0):

`readFile` is async function you need to do this

```
function final(){
        var arr;
        fs.readFile("/my/path/", 'utf8' ,(err, data) => {
            arr = parsing(data);
            arr.splice(-1,1);
            return arr;
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

or pass a callback function to final function

```
function callback(arr) {
//do something with arr
}

function final(callback) {
    var arr;
    fs.readFile("/my/path/", 'utf8' ,(err, data) => {
        arr = parsing(data);
        arr.splice(-1,1);
        callback(arr);
    });
}
```

As @Farhan Yassen's answer won't result correct behavior due to the async nature.

And also, you can always use synchronous version of the `readFile` with `readFileSync`